# Database design and query to get different device description under one inputed title

Tags: database, mongodb, vue.js, vuex

I am working on a project where a user create a new Audit giving it a title. then navigate to another page to add device description. However, since it's an audit, for each devices added, the user will have to add each device decriptions (device name, rating, quantity, and operation). And a user can have more one device. Now my problem is how to bind all the added devices and their description to the audit title. Such that, I'll be able to generate a recently created Audit using the Audit Title whist Onclick of the title, the added devices details will come up.

I've tried to use firestore but it wasnt working. So, I moved to mongoDB for better flexibility. However, I'm still lost on how to achieve this. Also, I've used vuex to bind each device input to the inputed Audit title on the front end, but still have not been able to achieve the database query part.

here is how i binded the title to the device added per session..

```
export default {
    computed:{
        device:{
            get: function(){
                return this.$store.state.device;
            },
            set: function(newDevice){
                //  alert(newDevice);
                this.$store.dispatch('addDevice', newDevice);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to be able to show a list of titles that generates all the devices binded to it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The code you posted is valid. How are you handling the logic on your server? What does your action `addDevice` do?

Comment: Thank you. the addDevice action is binded to the dashboard page where The audit tilte will show up. how ever, my database design is the problem. I want to design a database that catches the input devices and bind it to the assigned user title So that whenever i want to get my post, i will get by title and Onclick of the title, the binded devices will show up

Comment: There might be a misconception about what a database is and does. Do you really want to use a database like mongoDB, or simply store your data in memory at client side?